# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getters')

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuex-modules

Can anyone help with the below, I am getting the following error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getters')

I am working on a project where my stores should return an array to my index.vue

Is there also any way I can get around this without having to use the Vuex store?

My store directory contains the below files

index.js

```
export const state = () => ({})
```

parkingPlaces.js

```
import {getters} from '../plugins/base'

const state = () => ({
  all: []
});

export default {
  state,
  mutations: {
    SET_PARKINGPLACES(state, parkingPlaces) {
      state.all = parkingPlaces
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async ENSURE({commit}) {

        commit('SET_PARKINGPLACES', [
          {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Chandler Larson",
          "post": "37757",
          "coordinates": {
            "lng": -1.824377,
            "lat": 52.488583
          },
          "total_spots": 0,
          "free_spots": 0
        },
        ]
        )
      }
    },
  getters: {
    ...getters
  }
}
```

index.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="min-h-screen relative max-6/6" >
    <GMap class="absolute inset-0 h-100% bg-blue-400"
      ref="gMap"
      language="en"
      :cluster="{options: {styles: clusterStyle}}"
      :center="{lat:parkingPlaces[0].coordinates.lat, lng: parkingPlaces[0].coordinates.lng}"
      :options="{fullscreenControl: false, styles: mapStyle}"
      :zoom="5"
    >
      <GMapMarker
        v-for="location in parkingPlaces"
        :key="location.id"
        :position="{lat: location.coordinates.lat, lng: location.coordinates.lng}"
        :options="{icon: location.free_spots > 0 ? pins.spacefree : pins.spacenotfree}"
        @click="currentLocation = location"
      >
        <GMapInfoWindow :options="{maxWidth: 200}">
          <code>
            lat: {{ location.coordinates.lat }},
            lng: {{ location.coordinates.lng }}
          </code>
        </GMapInfoWindow>
      </GMapMarker>
      <GMapCircle :options="circleOptions"/>
    </GMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import {mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex';




export default {




 // async mounted() {
 //   //  // console.log('http://localhost:8000/api/parkingPlace')
 //   // console.log(process.env.API_URL)
 //   // const response = await this.$axios.$get('PARKING_PLACE')
 //   //
 //   //  console.log('response', response)
 //
 //   // console.log(location)
 //  },

  data() {
    return {
      currentLocation: {},
      circleOptions: {},
      // parkingPlaces: [
      //array of parkingPlaces
      // ],
      pins: {
        spacefree: "/parkingicongreen3.png",
        spacenotfree: "/parkingiconred3.png",
      },
      mapStyle: [],
      clusterStyle: [
        {
          url: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m1.png",
          width: 56,
          height: 56,
          textColor: "#fff"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      'parkingPlaces': "parkingPlaces/all"
    })
  },

  async fetch() {
    await this.ensureParking()
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      ensureParking: 'parkingPlaces/ENSURE'
    })
  }
 }
</script>
```

base.js

```
import getters from "./getters";

export {getters};
```

getters.js

```
export default {
  all: state => state.all
};
```

Image of my file directory below
[image]

image of error
[image]

Comment: can you add your file directory? 
or a screenshot

Comment: Hi @Delanovanlonden I have added this above

Comment: https://dev.to/jacobandrewsky/introduction-to-nuxt-3-modules-5h8o
this might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why you need state management :

> Vuex is a state management pattern + library for Vue.js applications. It serves as a centralized store for all the components in an application, with rules ensuring that the state can only be mutated in a predictable fashion.

**today you can try [nuxt3](https://nuxt.com/) then you have access to [Nuxt3](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/seo-meta) state management
or try [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) not Vuex
these are better options for Vue3.**

if you want to use Vue2, Nuxt2 and Vuex as state management so:

first why your getters file is in plugins?

use this structure:

|__store

⠀⠀|__ index.js

⠀⠀|__ getters.js

your getter file content should be like this :

```
export default {
 //your getters
};
```

then you can import these getters in your `index.js` file like this:

```
import getters from "./getters";
const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      something: 0
    }
  },
  getters
})
```

and then you use `mapGetters`:

```
...mapGetters({
  parkingPlaces: 'all'
})
```

if you have another store you should use modules :

```
const moduleA = {
  state: () => ({ ... }),
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... },
  getters: { ... }
}

const moduleB = {
  state: () => ({ ... }),
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... }
}

const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    a: moduleA,
    b: moduleB
  }
})
```

you can separate files and the structure will be:

|__ store

⠀⠀|__ index.js          # where we assemble modules and export the store

⠀⠀|__ actions.js        # root actions

⠀⠀|__mutations.js      # root mutations

⠀⠀|__ modules

⠀⠀⠀⠀|__ moduleA.js       # moduleA module

⠀⠀⠀⠀|__ moduleB.js   # moduleB module

Comment: Thank you for spending your precious time educate me on this. ;)

Comment: happy to help my friend

Answer (score 1):

In parkingPlaces.js: Try using `import {getters} from '../plugins/base.js'` instead of `import {getters} from '../plugins/base'`.

In base.us: try using `import getters from './getters.js'` instead of `import getters from './getters'`.

Comment: Hey, I have tried this numerous times before but does not seem to fix the error. Thank you for the input :)

Comment: I have also tried that but no luck :( I have gone through all the possible things it could be for days on end and this error is still there.

Comment: @newToBeingNerdy is there a line number with the error message? Or any other info?

Comment: I have updated my post above to show an image of the error, there are no errors in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you have namespace issue or your store isn't initialized in the right way.
Make sure that you register your `parkingPlaces.js` module with `namespaced` property -

```
import parkingPlacesModule from './parkingPlaces.js';
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    parkingPlaces: {
      namespaced: true,
      ...parkingPlacesModule
    }
  }
});
```

In addition, you can pass the name to the mapGetters helper, like that:

```
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('parkingPlaces', [
    'all', // -> this.all
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by below means

In getters.js

```
export const getters = {
  all: state => state.all
};
```

In base.js

```
export * from "./getters";
```

This above way will make your file `base.js` an object supplying the `getters` object.